# Работа AsyncTask в Service

Tags: android, сокет, service, android-asynctask

Есть класс, который наследует AsyncTask. В `protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids)`   у меня происходит подключение к серверу через `Socket`, идет постоянное прослушивание сокета на наличие новых данных. Так как это приложение должно постоянно работать и принимать данные с сервера, вопрос заключается в том, как это сделать.
Есть предположение, что AsynkTask должен работать внутри сервиса, вот только толковой реализации я не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Непонятно, в чем сомнения? Нужен AsyncTask, который не умрет? Запустите его при старте сервиса, прибейте при остановке.

Во-вторых, посмотрите на IntentService. Может быть вам и AsyncTask не потребуется.

```
public class DemoService extends Service {
    private DemoTask task;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        task = new DemoTask();
        task.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        task.cancel(true);
    }

    class DemoTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            DemoService.this.stopSelf();
        }
    }
}
```